# Simple heatmap in R not working with error `Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list''`

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to make a simple heatmap from a simple dataframe in R. The example is fully reproducible.

I have a simple data.frame from the breat cancer dataset.

```
data(BreastCancer, package="mlbench")
bc <- BreastCancer[complete.cases(BreastCancer), ]
```

I am using ggplot to try and create a simple heatmap using the following code:

```
x <- bc[2:9]
y <- bc[10]
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)

# Heatmap 
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

however I get the following error:

```
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I have followed the example on the ggplot2 guide and don't understand this error and a fairly new R user.

Could someone help please.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with the `expand.grid` line, but I don't think you got what you want there...

Comment: I was following the guide here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/79-levelplot-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: @Z.Lin I am used to python in which you can just call heatmap and it gives a correlation of all variables. I find crossing over confusing.

Answer (score 0):

what sort of plot are you looking for? You are giving ggplot a list where it expects a data.frame. Which variables do you want on the X and Y axes?

```
ggplot(data[[1]], aes(Cl.thickness, Cell.size)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

I feel like you may be wanting to plot this simply from `bc` data.frame.

```
ggplot(bc, aes(x = Cl.thickness, y = Cell.size)) + 
+ geom_tile(aes(fill = Cell.shape))
```

Based on your comment i think you need a different way to handle your data than `expand.grid` and then to use facet like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
xdat <- bc %>% gather(variable, value, -Id, - Mitoses)
ggplot(xdat, aes(x = Mitoses, y = value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking to view the correlation of all X variables to target variable y?

Comment: Or a heatmap of all variable correlation to each other variable.

Comment: you may also want to look up `corrplot`